# Code navigation breaks inside of $IFDEF blocks in Delphi 2010

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, conditional-compilation, code-navigation

I have a few conditionally compiled classes in my app.

```
{$IFDEF SOME_OPTION}
type
  TMyClass = class
    procedure Foo;
  end;
{$ENDIF}

...

{$IFDEF SOME_OPTION}
procedure TMyClass.Foo;
begin

end;
{$ENDIF}
```

That option SOME_OPTION is defined in "Project Options" - "Delphi Compiler" - "Conditional Defines" and in "Project Options" - "Resource Compiler" - "Directories and Conditionals" - "Defines a preprocessor symbol" for this project.

When I try to Ctrl+Click on their methods, nothing happens, code navigation don't want to work.

I use Delphi 2010. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I have had this problem even when SOME_OPTION is defined, just as you have experienced. It is a bug, and the chances of it being fixed are zero.   Even when it is defined in the Project Options for the current build.  But especially difficult would be if it was defined inside an options.inc file, rather than directly in your .dproj options.

Comment: Agree with @WarrenP Haven't been able to pin-point the problem. We do use inc file with options but locally defined conditionals as well. I am in the habit of building, not compiling so dcu's are unlikely not to match current define settings. Despite that, conditional defines and ctrl-clicking just seem at odds with eachother and have been since at least D2006, probably earlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bug, and the chances of it being fixed are zero.

/ Warren P

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the proper place is in "Project Options" - "Resource Compiler"...
But in "Project Options" - "**Delphi** Compiler" - "Conditional Defines".

Update:
I tried in Delphi XE here at work and whether it is defined or not, or where, does not seem to matter for Ctrl+Click to work for me in all cases.
Note that I have [Andreas Hausladen's IDE Fix Pack 4.6.6](http://andy.jgknet.de/blog/2012/01/ide-fix-pack-4-6-6-bug-fix-release/) and DDEv Extension 2.5 installed.
Do you use them?

Update 2:
When in the same unit, it seems to work, even when SOME_OPTION is undefined, **but** not when Foo is called from another unit.
What seem to work though is when it is properly defined in the Project Options **and** you rebuild the application (you see the blue dot on the line calling Foo). Then the IDE can use the compiler to locate the function source in the other unit.

That's all I can think of for the moment to help with that. And as has been stated already, it's not the best part of the IDE...

Comment: Sorry, I missed that place while typing the question. It is included there too

Comment: No matter you should remove the definitions from the resource compiler settings.

Comment: I used IDE Fix Pack and DDEv Extension 2.5 - no result

Comment: If the ifdef touches the class that is inherited from, funny things can happen iirc, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057510/known-constructs-that-crash-the-delphi-ide

Answer (score 0):

Is not working because you have not well defined your compilation directives. Directives must be defined as described here http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Delphi_compiler_directives in the **Using the IDE** section. A good practice is also to recompile the project after conditional directives are changed.

Comment: Even when I put {$DEFINE SOME_OPTION} into my dpr file, no change.